# JDBC authentication in Spring Boot for REST services

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-jdbc

Is there a way to use basic JDBC authentication with dataSource in Spring boot, but using a client writen in ReactJS? What should be sent to the client on login endpoint that we create?

Comment: You have to send request with header `Authorization` with `username` and `password` and if it is valid you should save header with username and password to `sessionStorage`/`localStorage` and send it with any request or use `HTTPInterceptor` which automaticlly add your header to requests.

Answer (score 0):

Create two filters

1.One is Authorization.

In authorization filter check for authentication validation.
Like request.getHeader("Authorization"). Then check this value in db for expiry or for any other kind of validity.

2.Create Authentication Filter

If Authorization token is not present then control goes to this filter. Auto wire jdbc template.
Authenticate with username and password.